# My Mac on Catalina himself wakes (sleep) up every two hours

Tags: terminal, mac, imac, catalina, sleep-wake

I am using iMac 5K 2019 (iMac 19.1) on Catalina 10.15.4.

Every night, my computer itself wakes up for a while, and then falls asleep back.

I can not understand what is the reason. I use the command **log show --style syslog | fgrep "[powerd: sleepWake]"** in Terminal and this is what I get. Why does my Mac wake up by itself?

```
2020-04-13 07:42:02.004283+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 331071862862
2020-04-13 07:42:02.027191+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No need to refresh inactivity prediction: phase=0, start=0.000000, now=608445722.027188
2020-04-13 07:42:02.027933+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x8019
2020-04-13 07:42:04.795993+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake end timestamp to 989214068991
2020-04-13 07:42:04.796049+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 0 -> 1
2020-04-13 07:42:04.796122+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] : due to RTC/Maintenance
2020-04-13 07:42:04.796216+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] WakeTime: 658.142 sec
2020-04-13 07:42:04.796560+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x19
2020-04-13 07:42:05.599389+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 330403808112
2020-04-13 07:42:50.514308+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] chooseStandbyDelay(): lowBattery = false, battery powered = false, capacity=0, lowBatteryThreshold=0; chosen delay=86400
2020-04-13 07:42:50.514848+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Eligible for Standby: 0
2020-04-13 07:42:50.514849+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] standbyDelay:86400 eligibleForStandby:0 elapsedTime:0 gDelta2Standby:86400
2020-04-13 07:42:50.514886+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2020-04-13 07:42:50.515014+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] connectionFireNotification: 0x0
2020-04-13 07:42:55.525691+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No AdaptiveWake is requested. InactivityEnd:Mon Jan  1 03:00:00 2001 PowerNap State:0
2020-04-13 09:42:57.002167+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 454490025069
2020-04-13 09:42:57.026501+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No need to refresh inactivity prediction: phase=0, start=0.000000, now=608452977.026500
2020-04-13 09:42:57.027006+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x8019
2020-04-13 09:42:57.509952+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] AppWoke:com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers Reason:BlueAvengers: Toggle beacon state
2020-04-13 09:42:57.510003+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "BlueAvengers: Toggle beacon state"  identity: "com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers"
2020-04-13 09:42:59.845515+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake end timestamp to 1048863801273
2020-04-13 09:42:59.845576+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 1 -> 1
2020-04-13 09:42:59.845624+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] : due to RTC/Maintenance
2020-04-13 09:42:59.845739+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] WakeTime: 594.374 sec
2020-04-13 09:42:59.845935+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x19
2020-04-13 09:43:00.461839+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 454026832150
2020-04-13 09:43:45.361332+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] chooseStandbyDelay(): lowBattery = false, battery powered = false, capacity=0, lowBatteryThreshold=0; chosen delay=86400
2020-04-13 09:43:45.366991+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Eligible for Standby: 0
2020-04-13 09:43:45.366991+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] standbyDelay:86400 eligibleForStandby:0 elapsedTime:0 gDelta2Standby:86400
2020-04-13 09:43:45.367044+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2020-04-13 09:43:45.367117+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] connectionFireNotification: 0x0
2020-04-13 09:43:50.379056+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No AdaptiveWake is requested. InactivityEnd:Mon Jan  1 03:00:00 2001 PowerNap State:0
2020-04-13 11:43:52.002036+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 514395451604
2020-04-13 11:43:52.025793+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No need to refresh inactivity prediction: phase=0, start=0.000000, now=608460232.025790
2020-04-13 11:43:52.026259+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x8019
2020-04-13 11:43:54.734051+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake end timestamp to 1108427856734
2020-04-13 11:43:54.734126+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 1 -> 1
2020-04-13 11:43:54.734209+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] : due to RTC/Maintenance
2020-04-13 11:43:54.734354+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] WakeTime: 594.032 sec
2020-04-13 11:43:54.734728+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x19
2020-04-13 11:43:55.091982+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 514173345167
2020-04-13 11:44:40.005951+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] chooseStandbyDelay(): lowBattery = false, battery powered = false, capacity=0, lowBatteryThreshold=0; chosen delay=86400
2020-04-13 11:44:40.006496+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Eligible for Standby: 0
2020-04-13 11:44:40.006497+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] standbyDelay:86400 eligibleForStandby:0 elapsedTime:0 gDelta2Standby:86400
2020-04-13 11:44:40.006548+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2020-04-13 11:44:40.006619+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] connectionFireNotification: 0x0
2020-04-13 11:44:45.018713+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No AdaptiveWake is requested. InactivityEnd:Mon Jan  1 03:00:00 2001 PowerNap State:0
2020-04-13 13:44:47.002070+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake start timestamp to 574504413907
2020-04-13 13:44:47.026254+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No need to refresh inactivity prediction: phase=0, start=0.000000, now=608467487.026253
2020-04-13 13:44:47.026669+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x8019
2020-04-13 13:44:47.423061+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] AppWoke:com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers Reason:BlueAvengers: Toggle beacon state
2020-04-13 13:44:47.423086+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "BlueAvengers: Toggle beacon state"  identity: "com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers"
2020-04-13 13:44:49.725430+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Updating wake end timestamp to 1167968158626
2020-04-13 13:44:49.725555+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 1 -> 1
2020-04-13 13:44:49.725618+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDN] : due to RTC/Maintenance
2020-04-13 13:44:49.725775+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] WakeTime: 593.464 sec
2020-04-13 13:44:49.726092+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] sendNoRespNotification: 0x19
2020-04-13 13:44:59.814480+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Next immediate inactivity window start:'2020-04-14 02:30:00 +0300' end:'2020-04-14 03:00:00 +0300'
2020-04-13 13:45:34.785712+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] chooseStandbyDelay(): lowBattery = false, battery powered = false, capacity=0, lowBatteryThreshold=0; chosen delay=86400
2020-04-13 13:45:34.786201+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Eligible for Standby: 0
2020-04-13 13:45:34.786201+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] standbyDelay:86400 eligibleForStandby:0 elapsedTime:0 gDelta2Standby:86400
2020-04-13 13:45:34.786248+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep'
2020-04-13 13:45:34.786319+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] connectionFireNotification: 0x0
2020-04-13 13:45:39.798911+0300  localhost powerd[125]: [powerd:sleepWake] No AdaptiveWake is requested. InactivityEnd:Mon Jan  1 03:00:00 2001 PowerNap State:0
```

Comment: You don’t happen to have Power Nap enabled that’s sporadically checking your Mac for updates/mail/sync etc when the Mac is sleeping? 

Check if power nap is enabled in Energy Saver settings in system preferences.

Comment: I have it all turned off. I also tried turning off Bluetooth, but my Mac wakes up every two hours anyway.